# Creating Retention Flags For Users Using Date_Diff in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a query that creates retention flags for users in BigQuery and my results are not matching what I'm seeing in firebase. I'm want to query tables only later than 2020-12-27. Current Query is:

```
 SELECT
distinct user_pseudo_id,
date(timestamp_micros(user_first_touch_timestamp)) as installdate,
max(case when date_diff(date(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp)), date(timestamp_micros(user_first_touch_timestamp)), DAY) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as d1,
max(case when date_diff(date(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp)), date(timestamp_micros(user_first_touch_timestamp)), DAY) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as d3,
max(case when date_diff(date(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp)), date(timestamp_micros(user_first_touch_timestamp)), DAY) = 7 then 1 else 0 end) as d7,
max(case when date_diff(date(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp)), date(timestamp_micros(user_first_touch_timestamp)), DAY) = 14 then 1 else 0 end) as d14,
FROM `events_table.analytics_xxxx.events_*`
where (_table_suffix > '20201227')
group by 1,2,3,4
```

Standard Bigquery Table looks like:

```
user_pseudo_id  event_timestamp      user_first_touch_timestamp
abc123           1616240916183001       1616240916183000
abc123            1716240916183001      1616240916183000
afg543           1718240916183020     1716240916183005
```

Where timestamps are unix_micros.

Data Output is currently formatted correctly, but retention appears to be higher in the query than what is in firebase

```
user_pseudo_id   installdate     d1  d3 d7
    abc123           2020-01-20   1  0  0
    afg543           2021-02-01   0  0  0
    trw423           2021-03-14   0  1  0
```

Where a '1' appears if a user had an event fire 1 day, 3 day, 7 day after install.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated